# Does media.playVideo() work on Corona SDK with windows OS

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm using Corona sdk, and just learnt the API media.playVideo("myfilename.mp4", true, listener).

When I open a blank file with only the code:

```
function showSuccess()
print( "success" )
end
media.playVideo( "hummingbird.mp4" , true, showSuccess)
```

The corona simulator displays nothing on screen, and the output is empty as well. On my android phone the video plays fine.

Question: Can corona simulator handle media.playVideo while i'm using a windows OS?
If not possible on Windows. How can I get around this? On bigger projects I would need the showSuccess function to print "success" in order to debug.

Thank you

Comment: It should be `( "hummingbird.mp4" , true, showSuccess )`

Answer (score 1):

Replace your last line by:

`media.playVideo( "hummingbird.mp4" , true, showSuccess)`

Your current line invokes the showSuccess method directly on the same line, instead of passing it as a function handle.